# Java menu looping

Tags: java, loops

I have a conversion program that will not cooperate with me.

It converts meters to:

1. Kilometers,
2. Inches,
3. Feet, or it
4. Exits the program.

My problem is that it is supposed to keep on going and allow you to enter choice 1, get the answer and keep entering choices until you hit 4 to end the program.

So far it ends after calculating the first choice or after telling that a distance in meters cannot be a negative number no matter what.

This is the first time I have asked a forum for help and I am VERY new to java so please keep it simple for me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConversionProgram
{

public static void showKilometers(double meters) //Converts Meters to Kilometers
    {
      double kilometers = meters * 0.001;
      System.out.println(meters + " meters is " + kilometers + " kilometers.");
    }

  public static void showInches(double meters) //Converts Meters to Inches
    {
      double inches = meters * 39.37;
      System.out.println(meters + " meters is " + inches + " inches.");
    }

  public static void showFeet(double meters) //Converts Meters to Feet
    {
      double feet = meters * 3.281;
      System.out.println(meters + " meters is " + feet + " feet.");
    }


  public static void quitProgram() {
    System.out.println("Bye!");
  }
  public static void showMenu() {
    System.out.println(" 1. Convert to Kilometers ");
    System.out.println(" 2. Convert to Inches ");
    System.out.println(" 3. Convert to Feet ");
    System.out.println(" 4. Quit the program ");
    System.out.println(" ");
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    double meters;
    int choice;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a Distance in Meters: ");
    meters = keyboard.nextDouble();

    if (meters < 1) {
      System.out.println("Meter can not be negative.");
    } else showMenu();
    choice = keyboard.nextInt();
    switch (choice) {
      case 1:
        showKilometers(meters);
        break;

      case 2:
        showInches(meters);
        break;

      case 3:
        showFeet(meters);
        break;

      case 4:
        quitProgram();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need some kind of loop, probably a do-while loop, check out [The while and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a loop and continue on asking for new input as long as user decides not to exit the program. You can begin this loop on the early steps of your program execution just before asking input from the user. Naturally there should be a condition in which your loop breaks. Considering the code you have provided I think it would make sense to use a boolean flag right under your exit choice. An example would be like below :

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ConversionProgram


{
    public static void showKilometers(double meters) //Converts Meters to Kilometers
    {
        double kilometers = meters * 0.001;
        System.out.println(meters + " meters is " + kilometers + " kilometers.");
    }

    public static void showInches(double meters) //Converts Meters to Inches
    {
        double inches = meters * 39.37;
        System.out.println(meters + " meters is " + inches + " inches.");
    }

    public static void showFeet(double meters) //Converts Meters to Feet
    {
        double feet = meters * 3.281;
        System.out.println(meters + " meters is " + feet + " feet.");
    }


    public static void quitProgram() {
        System.out.println("Bye!");
    }

    public static void showMenu() {
        System.out.println(" 1. Convert to Kilometers ");
        System.out.println(" 2. Convert to Inches ");
        System.out.println(" 3. Convert to Feet ");
        System.out.println(" 4. Quit the program ");
        System.out.println(" ");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double meters;
        int choice;

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Loop breaker
        boolean quitFlag = false;

        // Whole program wrapped around a loop
        while (!quitFlag) {
            System.out.println("Enter a Distance in Meters: ");
            meters = keyboard.nextDouble();

            if (meters < 1) {
                System.out.println("Meter can not be negative.");
            } else showMenu();
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    showKilometers(meters);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    showInches(meters);
                    break;

                case 3:
                    showFeet(meters);
                    break;

                case 4:
                    quitFlag = true;
                    quitProgram();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer has been flagged as a low quality answer. please provide some information or explanation

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do just keep your conversion logic in loop till you enter 4. One more suggestion when you enter the value less than 1 then its pause your program either exit the program or call the method to take input again and repeat all steps. Make method for that.For now I just copied your code in if block

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test {    


public static void showKilometers(double meters) // Converts Meters to // Kilometers                                        
{

    double kilometers = meters * 0.001;
    System.out.println(meters + " meters is " + kilometers + " kilometers.");           
}

public static void showInches(double meters) // Converts Meters to Inches
{
    double inches = meters * 39.37;
    System.out.println(meters + " meters is " + inches + " inches.");
}

public static void showFeet(double meters) // Converts Meters to Feet
{
    double feet = meters * 3.281;
    System.out.println(meters + " meters is " + feet + " feet.");
}

public static void quitProgram() {
    System.out.println("Bye!");
}

public static void showMenu() {
    System.out.println(" 1. Convert to Kilometers ");
    System.out.println(" 2. Convert to Inches ");
    System.out.println(" 3. Convert to Feet ");
    System.out.println(" 4. Quit the program ");
    System.out.println(" ");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int choice;
    double meters;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a Distance in Meters: ");
    meters = keyboard.nextDouble();
    do {
        if (meters < 1) {
            System.out
                    .println("Meter can not be negative and keep it greater then 0");
            System.out.println("Enter a Distance in Meters: ");
            meters = keyboard.nextDouble();
            showMenu();
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                showKilometers(meters);
                break;
            case 2:
                showInches(meters);
                break;
            case 3:
                showFeet(meters);
                break;

            case 4:
                quitProgram();
                break;
            }
        } else
            showMenu();
        choice = keyboard.nextInt();
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            showKilometers(meters);
            break;
        case 2:
            showInches(meters);
            break;
        case 3:
            showFeet(meters);
            break;

        case 4:
            quitProgram();
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 4);
}}
```

Comment: thank you, i have saved all of the answers for future reference. I still have much to learn. Maybe i should try some youtube videos.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your choices inside **while loop** which will run indefinitely and in `quitProgram()` you should write **System.exit(0)** to exit from your program.

Comment: I think its `System.exit()` not `System.out.exit()`